# What does the shadow cache option exactly do in the Resident Evil 4 remake?

Tags: pc, resident-evil-4-2023

The *Resident Evil 4* remake on PC has the graphics option "shadow cache". What does it exactly do? The comparison picture they provide does not really show any difference. Is it dynamic or for moving objects? I can't seem to find any source for this specific game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's self-explanatory; it's caching shadows into your RAM and VRAM. What that setting does is that it loads up all the static (and probably even some of dynamic) shadows in an area to improve performance (only if player's PC is having good specs, e. g. having nice amount of RAM/VRAM) as a player progresses through that area (as opposed to loading those shadows as they would normally become observable to player). So yes, you can't see any difference in its quality.

If you have sufficient RAM/VRAM (I think around 16GB of RAM and 8GB of VRAM), you should experience higher FPS. For example, I've got a 32GB of RAM and 8GB of VRAM, and setting this setting OFF gives me ~110FPS at village (Mercenary map), but setting ON gives me ~140FPS. That difference is massive, really.